# Real time Bubble chart with Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

I need to create a bubble chart with real time data. Bubble should move according to the changes in the data. I tried using API streaming data set. But Real time data support only few chart types as per the image below. Is there any workaround to achieve my requirement?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No at the moment only those visuals are supported for real time as they are dash board objects, however coming soon is refresh in Power BI Desktop, that will allow you to set a [refresh on a report](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform-release-plan/2019wave2/business-intelligence/automatic-page-refresh). Microsoft demo'ed it to show the report reading telemetry from a game. This may meet your requirement, for a 'realtime' data or at least low level latency